# Xcode 9.1 taking too much time to compile

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode9.1

i m running on ios 11.1 and Xcode 9.1, Xcode taking too much time to compile, every time it stops by saying

> Compliling Swift source files

Can any one please tell me what is wrong or how to resolve this issue.

Comment: yes there is some bug i also facing also some time creates new app icon in simulator or from one we cant remove

Comment: I am seeing this as well. The times are not consistent, but may range from 6 to 20 minutes on one project. Our app build times have typically been in the 40-50 minute range when building from a clean sandbox. They can now extend over two hours.

Comment: any solutions to this @NealS.

Comment: I don't have any solutions yet. We run three build servers. One of them builds in our previous build time range; the other two will consistently hit our three hour build timeout period. We can't figure out whether the first server has some unrecognized difference from the other two or if we just haven't see enough builds on the first server to see the problem yet.